# ASP.NET MVC add class and image to an anchor element

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an anchor element with an image inside and I would like to use the @Html.ActionLink from ASP.Net MVC to create it:

```
<a class="element image-button image-left place-left" style="color: #3D1400">
   Some text here
   <img src="~/Content/Images/logo.png" />
</a>
```

Can anyone help me to do it? thanks

Comment: So, there is not possible way to do it with Html.ActionLink, just with Action and putting the rest of the Html as usually?

Comment: @yosoy In a project I worked on a while back we used a custom HtmlHelper named ImageActionLink for just this type of situation, so you could have a go at implementing such a thing.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try it too. For now I solved using the @Url.Action. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ActionLink one can do the following in the view

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Details", "Detail", new { @class = "detailsIcon"})
```

and in your style sheet you can define something like

```
.detailsIcon
{
  background: url(AnImage.png);
}
```

Comment: Yes, even Url.Action() as suggested by @Nathan is great.

Comment: Thanks, even when I solved with Url.Action, considering that the question was using Html.ActionLink I believe that your anwser is the most accurate.

Answer (score 2):

So I found a way of doing it with the @Url.Action method, instead of @Html.ActionLink

```
<a class="element image-button image-left place-left" style="color: #3D1400" href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
         Some text here
      <img src="~/Content/Images/logo.png" />
</a>
```

thanks @Nathan Koop for the link.